# Numpy broadcasting comparison report "'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'" error when dealing with large dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, broadcasting

I use numpy broadcasting to get the differences matrix from a pandas dataframe. I find when dealing with large dataframe, it reports "'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'" error. While dealing with small dataframe, it runs fine.

I post the two csv files in the following links:
[large file](https://genesclouds.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/test_large.csv)
[small file](https://genesclouds.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/test_small.csv)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_small = pd.read_csv(r'test_small.csv',index_col='Key')
df_small.fillna(0,inplace=True)
a_small = df_small.to_numpy()
matrix = pd.DataFrame((a_small != a_small[:, None]).sum(2), index=df_small.index, columns=df_small.index) 
print(matirx)
```

when running this, I could get the difference matrix.
[image]

**when switch to large file, It reports the following error. Does anybody know why this happens?**

EDIT:The numpy version is 1.19.5

```
np.__version__
'1.19.5'
```

[image]

Comment: What are the exact shapes for the big and small arrays when trying to do the element-wise comparsion?

Comment: The shape of large array is (8599, 3002), the shape of small array is (19, 7)

Comment: Ok, just tried creating a creating an array with ```np.random.randn(8599, 3002)``` and can see that it returns a bool instead of doing the element-wise comparison, which is why it throws an error. If you try and run ```np.not_equal(a_small, a_small[:, None])``` you will get a more transparent error message: numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 207. GiB for an array with shape (8599, 8599, 3002) and data type bool.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Kevin. I want to get the difference matrix of large dataframe, do you have good idea?